# Слова "дюжий" и "недужный"

Tags: этимология, семантика

Слова ***дюжий*** и ***недужный*** близки или далеки с точки зрения этимологии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Близки](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F).

> Происходит от сущ. недуг, из праслав. , от кот. в числе прочего
>   произошли: ст.-слав. недѫгъ (νόσος, νόσημα; Клоц., Супр.), русск.
>   недуг, болг. недъ́г, чешск., словацк. neduh — то же; **связано с -дуг,
>   дюжий**, ср. чешск. duh «процветание, удача», словацк. duh «сила»,
>   польск. dążyć «стремиться, поспевать за кем-либо»